# Adding method to existing interface implication on several files

Tags: java, eclipse, search, interface, refactoring

I am working on a existing project. To add some functionality I had to add one method in one Interface,  now because method is added in interface, is has to be implemented by all the classes which implements it. I searched in one module and found 10 classes which implements this Interface. But now I will search the same in other modules, and in whole project. So this has two problems :

Searching for the classes which implements that specific Interface.

- I can not import whole project in eclipse as the code-base is large.
- Searching for classes which implements an Interface, can write it like : `Class A implements ChangedInterface` and `Class A implements B, ChangedInterface`, so even searching using grep will be difficult.

I want to get the suggestion from you.

**Edit** : I can not avoid adding method in that Interface.
Code base is 20 GB, importing in eclipse looks difficult to me.

Comment: Really - you can't import the entire project. I have had massive bloat ware projects in Eclipse and could search them. It took a while but it worked.

Comment: Keep it simple. Rebuild and see where you get errors, or grep for the interface name (mayby add a regexp to include implements. Then rebuild. And I have worked with the java source of android in eclipse. Your project must be big.

Comment: Also why don't you implement an abstact class that implements that inferace, witch in turn has the default method implementation. All that you have to do from there on is to extend from that abstact class, instead of implementing from Interface A.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to search? Just compile and look at the errors. If you haven't automated your build process, fix that! Also, if not all classes need to implement this method, try extending the interface rather than adding a method.

Comment: building whole project may fall because of others code change, It will  un-necessarily waste lot of time in building a 20gig project.

Comment: Well, the other options have already been discussed. Fix your build process or go for a walk while your project builds. Other errors should not prevent the compiler from reporting unimplemented methods.

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    ...
    ...
    public void newMethod();
}

public abstract class AbstractClassA implements InterfaceA {
   public void newMethod() {
      //do Stuff
   }
}
```

And then change all `implements IntefaceA` to `extends AbstractClassA`, this way all inheriting classes will have the default implementation of newMethod.

Also in case the methods do not differ you will avoid duplicate code.

Comment: It's same problem as finding which class implements InterfaceA. Also it will create problem as moving on from implements to extents ( you can not extend multiple classes).